# Disable/hide specific anchor tag based on ID in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have multiple links on my page. Out of many links I want to disable particular links only based on database value. i have kept the ID of the anchor tag equal to ID of database in firebase so that based on value disable link of that particular ID.

```
 <a  id="{{page.$id}}"  ng-href="#/edit/{{page.$id}}/" target="_blank">Add</a>
```

If I click on a button then I have added below code and it works fine:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="complete(page.$id)">Complete</button>

$scope.complete=function(id)
{
   var target=angular.element("a#"+id);
   console.log(target);
   target[0].hidden=true;
   var elem= angular.element(id);
   elem.context.activeElement.disabled=true;
}
```

Above code console.log returns me the element like this:

```
[a#-KBp32nu3tfHPpKvlBqW, prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context:  document, selector: "a#-KBp32nu3tfHPpKvlBqW"]
 0: a#-KBp32nu3tfHPpKvlBqW
 context: document
 length: 1
 prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
 selector: "a#-KBp32nu3tfHPpKvlBqW"
 __proto__: x[0]
```

Through this I am able to fetch particular anchor tag ID and able to hide that element.
However when I am trying to apply the same code on controller so as to disable/hide element on page load then this function returns me the element of parentDOM .
My code on controller looks like this:

```
refUpdate=new Firebase("https://databseURL/"+newId);
refUpdate.on('value',function(snapshot){
var status= snapshot.child("completed").val();
if(status=="yes")
{
   var target= angular.element('a#'+newId);
   console.log(target);
}
});

[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector:"a#-KBp32nu3tfHPpKvlBqW"]
 context: document
 length: 0
 prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1]
 selector: "a#-KBp32nu3tfHPpKvlBqW"
 __proto__: x[0]
```

So I am not able to get the selector value.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You could use `ng-class`

Comment: @RayonDabre Well I think ng-class will make all the links disabled present on the page and Lani is saying that the links are getting populated dynamically!

Comment: @CEOUnderworld, On change of `scope` value, digestion cycle is run again..and all the directive will go through that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you will have database `values` in `boolean`, you can use that in `a` tag like:

```
<a  id="{{page.$id}}"  ng-href="#/edit/{{page.$id}}/" target="_blank" ng-hide="page.isHide">Add</a>
```

you can use `ng-disabled`, if you want to `disable`

Comment: Thanks. I added one boolean value in the database and based on that I am able to hide the element.